# Creature forcing/a request for reference

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

I'm looking for a paper/book/volume treating the forcing with **creatures.**
I've found one by [Roslanowski-Shelah](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/470/), but this one is too much complicated.
Are all references similarly complicated? Some gentle introduction would be welcome.

**Can someone reading this post write such a paper and give here a link to it** ?

Comment: Sadly, that's the simplest text I've found on the subject - I'm excited to hear of a better one, though! (I don't know why there's the large cardinals tag here, though.)

Comment: The tag has been fixed. Do you mean that there are yet more complicated texts?

Comment: Forcing is technical and complicated. There are things which cannot be simplified without *a lot* of work which tantamount to just learning the existing texts and techniques. I don't know if there is a simpler text on creature forcing. I imagine there might be something written by Martin Goldstern or one of his cohort, and that it might be more appealing. But there is only so much you can do to simplify creature forcing.

Comment: I agree that "There are things which cannot be simplified without a lot of work which tantamount to just learning the existing texts and techniques. " but someone more competent than me could have do this, right? There are some (20) papers on ArXive, but none of them expalins the basics of creature forcing, but rather a mixture of additional topics.

Comment: Step I: Read "Games with creatures" by Shelah and Zapletal (which focuses on some very basic examples of creature forcing) and the relevant examples in chapter 4 of Zapletal's "Forcing idealized" (which also shows an interesting correspondence between certain types of creature forcings and Hausdorff submeasures). Step II: Read some of the relevant papers by Kellner and Shelah. Step III: Write a paper with Shelah on creature forcing. Step IV: Read the Roslanowski-Shelah book. That was my path into creature forcing, and is still the easiest path that I can think of.

Comment: @Haim: I wouldn't say that you're the epitome of "easy paths", though. :-) [I'm not disagreeing with your outline, though, just making a point.]

Comment: @Haim I love that step III comes before step IV.

Comment: @Haim I think you should give that (at least I and II) as an answer: I don't think there will be a better one, and the Shelah/Zapletal and Zapletal texts might be new to the OP and other readers of this question so it really does contribute something.